# Write multiple logs for tests with log4net

Tags: c#, testing, logging, automation, log4net

I'm running tests in parallel.
Can you use log4net to write a seperate log file for each test?
If so, how can this be implemented?

Comment: Why are you using a logger apart from your test framework? You should be stubbing out your production logging during unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to achieve that by adding appenders in App.config, and filtering the loggerToMatch property value by test name.

And named the logger with the test name: 
`ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.Name)`